# PHP SELECT query not outputting data

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have turned on the errors and tested the SQL query, everything appears to be fine, but it will not output any data from the selected row!

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
$Lesson_id=$_REQUEST['Lesson_id'];
$user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
$Lesson_Class_id=$_REQUEST['Lesson_Class_id'];
$class_id=$_REQUEST['class_id'];
$Class_List_id=$_REQUEST['Class_List_id'];


$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT Lesson_CLass.R1, Lesson_Planner.Q1, Lesson_Planner.G1, Lesson_CLass.I1, Lesson_CLass.F1, Class_List.Class_List_id, Class_List.user_id, User_Accounts_.user_id, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname FROM Lesson_CLass, Lesson_Planner, Class_List, User_Accounts_ WHERE (Lesson_Planner.Lesson_id = ?) AND (Lesson_CLass.Lesson_id=Lesson_Planner.Lesson_id) AND (Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id=Class_List.Class_List_id) AND (Class_List.user_id=User_Accounts_.user_id) AND (Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id=?)');


$stmt -> bind_param('ii', $Lesson_id, $Class_List_id);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($R1,$Q1, $G1, $I1, $F1, $Class_List_id, $user_id, $user_id, $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt -> fetch();

echo $firstname;
```

Comment: BTW, you can use aliases for tables in queries that are shorter. That can help to make the fully qualified referencing of columns less convoluted. And there is an explicit `JOIN` syntax that is usually easier to read and write and should therefore preferred over comma separated lists of tables in the `FROM` clause. And there's no need to put `=` operations in `()`. They will take precedence over `AND` (and other logical operations) without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the query is returning 0 records based on the variables being input.

Try checking $stmt -> num_rows to see if any rows are being returned

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
$Lesson_id=$_REQUEST['Lesson_id'];
$user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
$Lesson_Class_id=$_REQUEST['Lesson_Class_id'];
$class_id=$_REQUEST['class_id'];
$Class_List_id=$_REQUEST['Class_List_id'];


$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT Lesson_CLass.R1, Lesson_Planner.Q1, Lesson_Planner.G1, Lesson_CLass.I1, Lesson_CLass.F1, Class_List.Class_List_id, Class_List.user_id, User_Accounts_.user_id, User_Accounts_.firstname, User_Accounts_.lastname FROM Lesson_CLass, Lesson_Planner, Class_List, User_Accounts_ WHERE (Lesson_Planner.Lesson_id = ?) AND (Lesson_CLass.Lesson_id=Lesson_Planner.Lesson_id) AND (Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id=Class_List.Class_List_id) AND (Class_List.user_id=User_Accounts_.user_id) AND (Lesson_CLass.Class_List_id=?)');


$stmt -> bind_param('ii', $Lesson_id, $Class_List_id);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$rowCount = $stmt -> num_rows;
$stmt -> bind_result($R1,$Q1, $G1, $I1, $F1, $Class_List_id, $user_id, $user_id, $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt -> fetch();

echo $rowCount;
```